# Google Sheet to Pdf Inside of Folder and Mange Pdf Ownership

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, pdf-generation, google-sheets-api

```
function PDF() {
  var sheetName = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var folderID = "My Folder Id";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('My Spreadsheets Id');
  var pdfName = "Invoice " + ss.getRange("A1:A1").getValue(); 
  var sourceSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sourceSheet = sourceSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID);
  var destSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.open(DriveApp.getFileById(sourceSpreadsheet.getId()).makeCopy("tmp_convert_to_pdf", folder))
  var sheets = destSpreadsheet.getSheets();
  var theBlob = destSpreadsheet.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf').setName(pdfName);
  var newFile = folder.createFile(theBlob);
  DriveApp.getFileById(destSpreadsheet.getId()).setTrashed(true);
}
```

The real problem is that, If a user of the share sheet creates a pdf then he has to become an owner of pdf.

spouse:

- I am the owner admin@company.com Gmail
- And share, google sheet and folder to the user

**Code running fine**

if the user "user: user@company.com" run the function he has to become a personal owner of pdf. **that's my problem how to manage this ownership part.**

create pdf any use but the owner always admin@company.com Gmail

**it creates pdf and saves inside of folder by name**

```
   var pdfName = "Invoice " + ss.getRange("A1:A1").getValue();
```

Comment: setOwner(emailAddress) 
Changes the owner of the File. This method also gives the previous owner explicit edit access to the File.

Comment: Is `"My Folder Id"` a folder on a Shared drive or on your private Drive to which the user has edit access?